# how to give multiple values to a picker? like an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to show a dropdown of 4 values in picker component,
if i have array currencies,

```
    import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
 let currencies=['pound','euro','USD Dollor']
or
    let currencies = [
        {country: 'UK', currency: 'GBP', currencylabel: 'pound'},
        {country: 'EU', currency: 'EUR', currencylabel: 'euro'},
        {country: 'USA', currency: 'USD', currencylabel: 'USD Dollor'},
      ];
    
    <Picker
           selectedValue={state.currency}
           onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.pickerChange(itemIndex)}
          >
            {currencies.map(v => {
              return <Picker.Item color="red" label={v.currencyLabel} value={v.currency} key={v.currency}/>;
            })}
          </Picker>
```

I want to show all the values in currencylabel in a drop-down? but the solution does not work
or if I have just had an array of objects like,
currencies=['pound','euro','USD Dollor']how to implement ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, [Picker is deprecated](https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker).

Per the docs' suggestion, I would try [`react-native-select-multiple`](https://github.com/tableflip/react-native-select-multiple):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import SelectMultiple from 'react-native-select-multiple'

const fruits = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears']
// --- OR ---
// const fruits = [
//   { label: 'Apples', value: 'appls' },
//   { label: 'Oranges', value: 'orngs' },
//   { label: 'Pears', value: 'pears' }
// ]

class App extends Component {
  state = { selectedFruits: [] }

  onSelectionsChange = (selectedFruits) => {
    // selectedFruits is array of { label, value }
    this.setState({ selectedFruits })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <SelectMultiple
          items={fruits}
          selectedItems={this.state.selectedFruits}
          onSelectionsChange={this.onSelectionsChange} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna still use array like ['pound','euro','USD Dollor'] instead, you can still use map, as follow :

```js
currencies.map((item, key) => {
         return <Picker.Item color="red" label={item} value={item} key={key}/>
}
```

to iterate using array, instead of array of object

Comment: can you share any error message, and your currencies array ? @userrr

Comment: no errors but dropdown isnt seen on screen.

Comment: try returning the text, or other element instead of Picker, if that also doesn't work, means your loop had nothing to do with the dropdown. have you tried solution from @Blumenthaler ?

Comment: <Picker
            {currencies.map((item, key) => {
              return (
                <Picker.Item color="red" label={item} value={item} key={key} />
              );
            })}>
          </Picker>

Comment: my array is  let currencies = ['pound', 'euro', 'USD Dollor'];

Comment: yes, if you wanted to return Picker item, it should be like this
<Picker> {currencies.map((item, key) => { return ( <Picker.Item color="red" label={item} value={item} key={key} /> ); })} </Picker>

Comment: Please do not take the information for granted and copy-paste it directly. Kindly provide more information on the updated progress of your code so we could help with more detailed answer